# arithmetics on selected DOM element text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple jQuery `$("span.value")` which select nodes containing text. This text is guaranteed to be an integer. How do I calculate the sum of all selected node's text, and place the sum into another node?

```
<span class="value">3</span>
<span class="value">4</span>
<span class="value">5</span>
<span class="sum">?</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var sum = 0;    
$('.value').each(function(index, el) {
    sum += parseInt($(this).text());
});
$('.sum').text(sum); //careful - will set the text for *all* elements with class = sum
```

I'd suggest using an `id` instead of a class for the sum `<span>`, even if you're sure there's going to be just one. IMO, it's be less error-prone..

Comment: ID will be faster than class as well, along with some context. $('span#sum')